# How to get the datafile version number of optimizely in iOS SDK?

Tags: ios, objective-c, optimizely

How to get the datafile version/revision number from Optimizely's json file in iOS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question seems to be missing a lot of information that would be helpful. I'm not familar with Optimizely, but I dove into their documentation and found and example json formatted Datafile

[The example data file shown here](https://docs.developers.optimizely.com/full-stack/docs/example-datafile) shows that the version number would be found under the key `version` and the revision number under the `revision` key.

If you have the file locally you would access the version and revision info like this:

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"datafile" ofType:@"json"];
NSError *error;
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:path];
NSDictionary *dataDict =  [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error];
if(error) { return; } // or handle the error however you want
NSString *version = dataDict[@"version"];
NSString *revision = dataDict[@"revision"];
```

If you need to grab the datafile from their server, you'll need to make a request to the appropriate end point, then serialize the JSON response. Here's the documentation I found for getting the datafile:  https://docs.developers.optimizely.com/full-stack/docs/get-the-datafile#section-access-the-datafile-via-the-app

Answer (score 1):

Datafile `version` and datafile `revision` are two separate concepts.

The `version` is the internal schema version of the datafile. This is incremented whenever the datafile has new fields added to its schema like when Optimizely added feature flags.

The `revision` refers to which revision of your Optimizely project the datafile is at. Whenever you make a change to your Optimizely project, a new datafile is generated and the revision number is incremented.

You can get either by calling

```
OPTLYClient *client = [OPTLYManager initialize];
OPTLYProjectConfig *config = client.config;
NSString *version = config.version;
NSString *revision = config.revision;
```

Comment: Property 'config' not found on object of type 'OPTLYClient *'